# not scraping the html source, but the actual website

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest, bigdata

I am working on a project where I want to scrape a page like this, in order to get the city of origin. I tried to use the css selector: ".type-12~ .type-12+ .type-12" However I do not get the text into R.

Link:
https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1141096871/support-ctrl-shft/description

I use rvest and and the read_html function.

However, it seems that the source has some scripts in it. Is there a way to scrape the website after the scripts have returned their results (as you see it with a browser)?

PS I looked at similar questions but did find the answer..

Code:

```
    main.names <- read_html(x = paste0("https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1141096871/support-ctrl-shft/description")) # feed `main.page` to the next step
    names1 <- main.names %>% # feed `main.page` to the next step
    html_nodes("div.mb0-md") %>% # get the CSS nodes
    html_text()# extract the text
```

Answer (score 3):

You should not do it. They provide a API which you can find here: https://status.kickstarter.com/api

Using APIs or Ajax/JSON calls is usually better since

1. The server isn't overused because your **scraper** visits every link it can find causing unnecessary traffic. That is bad for the speed of your program and bad for the servers of the site you are scraping.
2. You don't have to worry about that they changed a class name or id and your code won't work anymore

Especially the second part should interest you since it can take hours finding which class isn't returning a value anymore.

But to answer your question:

When you use the right scraper you can find all what you want. What tools are you using? There are possibilities to get data before the site is loaded or after. You can execute the JS on the site separately and find hidden content or find things like `display:none` Css classes...

It really depends on what you are using and how you use it.

Comment: this api does not provide any information on the country of origin or other information about the project. Or am I missing something? The only possibilities I see are are related to actions or maintenance updates.

Comment: http://syntaxi.net/2013/03/24/let-s-explore-kickstarter-s-api/
https://github.com/markolson/kickscraper

And again. What tools are you using? With BeatifulSoup (its python not R) I could get the infos.

Comment: I am using R:       main.names <- read_html(x = paste0("https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1141096871/support-ctrl-shft/description")) # feed `main.page` to the next step
names1 <- main.names %>% # feed `main.page` to the next step
  html_nodes("div.mb0-md") %>% # get the CSS nodes
  html_text()# extract the film names (See edit)